# Runnable JavaCV Project

Tags: java, dll, opencv, jar

I'm developing a short application using the OpenCV wrapper, JavaCV. I tried to run a basic example and it worked on my computer without any problems.

Now I run into Problems, when I try to execute the same program on my laptop. OpenCV is not installed there, but the OpenCV binaries are included in the JavaCV jars, which are included in my jar file.

So my question is if there is a chance to create a runnable jar file that can be executed on any Ubuntu or Windows system where OpenCV is not installed.

Thanks and best regards

Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but given Java and C++'s limitations as well as licensing issues from Microsoft, the easiest way would be to link statically everything you need in one massive JNI library, one per platform. This can be done by modifying the directories at the top of the `opencv_core.java` file and point them to the static libs, and by using the `-o myMassiveJNIlib` option of JavaCPP (see inside the `build.xml` file of JavaCV). In your applications then simply call System.load('path/to/myMassiveJNIlib') before using JavaCV. We can also call `Loader.extractResource()` on the relevant library file included in the JAR file (possibly with filenames based on `Loader.getPlatformName()`) to extract it into a temporary file, before calling `System.load()` on it. This is what JavaCPP does automatically for each class, when we do not need to merge everything in one big massive file.

EDIT: Recent versions of JavaCPP and JavaCV can extract and load from resources native libraries, as shown by the [FaceApplet sample](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/HowToMakeAnApplet). No need to mess with static libraries anymore.